# Adding Custom Elements/Controls to react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I'm using and I want to basically create a clone from [google maps search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujDuE.jpg)

My markers, places, location, and bounds state are managed by App then passed down as props to the higher order component. So I have all the necessary data, just unsure how to add my container to the map.

How would I go about using the map reference in this [solutions](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/161#issuecomment-310553564) and adding a custom controller/component to it?

Any thorough descriptions would be greatly appreciated!